# Page class in body gone

Tags: theming

I am currently working on an old Drupal website. I had to upgrade the version from `7.19` to `7.61`. After this update, everything is still working except for one thing. Before the update when you went to `website.com/en/people` the body had the class `page-people`. After the update, the body doesn't have this class anymore. I tried to find a setting to define a class or something but couldn't find anything.

The HTML code for the body tag is:

```
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: check if [template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x) implemented in your `template.php` or somewhere else.

Comment: @berramou just checked. Can't find the function in the theme directory. I checked for bootstrap_preprocess_html (theme name) and theme_preprocess_html. But the code didn't change, why is it working for the old version but not for the latest?

Comment: I added the `bootstrap_preprocess_html` class with logic to add the page-{name} class. It's working now. But I still don't get why it was working before then. The theme code hasn't changed.